# testing form validation with HTML5 validation API and pseudo-selector with nightwatch API

Tags: nightwatch.js

I have a typical login form with email and password and submit button. Password and email fields are required, i.e. the required attribute on the form is set. This is such that when the user clicks submit and for instance the email field is empty, the error 'Please fill in the field' pops up. That works fine in manual testing.

The issue is that I want to automate that check with nightwatch, and I thought of the following :

- using `:invalid` pseudo-selector : `.assert.cssClassPresent('.c-textfield__input--password', ':invalid')`. However, this fails as it only finds `.c-textfield__input--password` as a class defined on the input element.
- access the `validity` property (`.assert.attributeEquals('.c-textfield__input--email', 'validity', 'somevalue)`). But that fails too.

`Testing if attribute validity of <.c-textfield__input--email> equals "somevalue". Element does not have a validity attribute.  - expected "somevalue" but got: "null"`

Does anybody know how to automate the form validation testing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to do it by using a custom assertion.

In a file `test/e2e/custom-assertions/isValidInput.js` :

```
exports.assertion = function (selector, stateAttr, stateValue) {
  this.message = 'Testing if element <' + selector + '> has ValidityState ' + stateAttr + ': ' + stateValue
  this.expected = stateValue

  this.pass = function (val) {
    return val === this.expected
  }

  this.value = function (res) {
    return res.value[stateAttr]
  }

  this.command = function (cb) {
    var self = this
    return this.api.execute(
      function (selector) {
        return document.querySelector(selector).validity
      },
      [selector],
      function (res) {
        cb.call(self, res)
      }
    )
  }
}
```

Then you can use it that way for example for a required empty input form :

```
browser
  .assert.isValidInput('#form-input-id', 'valid', false)
  .assert.isValidInput('#form-input-id', 'valueMissing', true)
```

Don't forget to load the custom assertion. For me, I had to add this in my `nightwatch.conf.js` file :

```
module.exports = {
  ...
  custom_assertions_path: ['test/e2e/custom-assertions'],
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I'm getting `Converting circular structure to JSON` on this line; ` this.api.execute(function(selector){` any thoughts?

Comment: No idea, it seems that you have a JS object somewhere which is converted to JSON (either by a toString call or by a json.stringify call) and it references itself in one of its child attribute.

Comment: Weird, It might have been to do with the version of nightwatch. I had to change it to this; https://gist.github.com/Dayjo/bc15d50540604d99507a5b937a085967 Thanks for your help